# How to use localeCompare when sorting strings in Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, sorting

For example, `chineseName.sort((function(a,b){return a.localeCompare(b)}));`
The javascript function localeCompare works well for IE and firefox, but not in Chrome.
Dose anyone know how to make the code compatible for Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I have just search the whole www to find an answer, but alas nothing... So I made my own code. It is for danish letters, so it's probably not worth a lot to you, but maybe someone else comes along in search of an answer. This is my first answer to a question, so be gentle...

convert function: The convertfunction is to convert the 'double-a' (danish) [aa] to the danish letter [å]. This will make it easier to compare character by character later.

danishCompareCharacter function: This function is the actual compare function. It goes for the specific danish characters 'æ', 'ø' and 'å', which are in the END of the danish alfabet.

danishCompareString function: Which is the custom sort function used as a parameter in javascript sort function.

```
function convert(stringToConvert)
{
    var returnString = new String();
    var tempLetter;
    for (var j = 0; j < stringToConvert.length; j++)
        {
            if (stringToConvert.toLowerCase()[j] == 'a' &&         stringToConvert.toLowerCase()[j + 1] == 'a')
                {
                    tempLetter = 'å';
                    j++;
                } else
                {
                    tempLetter = stringToConvert.toLowerCase()[j];

                }
            returnString = returnString + tempLetter;
        }
    return returnString;
}

function danishCompareCharacter(firstCharacter, secondCharacter) {
    if ((firstCharacter == 'æ') || (firstCharacter == 'ø') || (firstCharacter == 'å')) {
            if (secondCharacter == 'æ' || secondCharacter == 'ø' || secondCharacter == 'å') {
                    if (firstCharacter == secondCharacter) {
                            return 0;
                        } 
                        if ((firstCharacter == 'æ') || secondCharacter == 'å')
                                {
                                    return -1;
                                }
                            if ((firstCharacter == 'å') || secondCharacter == 'æ') {
                                    return 1;
                                }
                            }
                return 1;
            } 
    if (secondCharacter == 'æ' || secondCharacter == 'ø' || secondCharacter == 'å') {
            return -1;
        }
        if(firstCharacter==secondCharacter){
                return 0;}
    if( firstCharacter < secondCharacter)
        {
            return -1;
        } 
        return 1;
}

function danishCompareString(a, b)
{
    var result = 0;
    var length = b.length;
    if (a.length < b.length)
        {
            length = a.length;
        }
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result = danishCompareCharacter(a[i], b[i]);
            if (result != 0)
                {
                    return result;
                } 
            }
    return result;
}

function SortMyArray(arr) {
//This works in ALL browsers
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (danishCompareString(convert(a[0]), convert(b[0])));

    //And this would have worked in any browser BUT chrome...
    //        if (a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) == 0) { return 0; }
    //        if (a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) < 0) { return -1; }
    //        else { return 1; }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in Chrome just fine now (5 years later).

Since you mentioned Chinese names, the function to sort an array of Chinese names would be:

```
chineseNames.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'zh-CN');
});
```

In ES2015 it would be:

```
chineseNames.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'zh-CN'));
```

See http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html for other language identifiers.